# Cann't get the router in composition api by useRouter()?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-composition-api

```html
<script setup>
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'

const menus = useRouter();
console.log(menus);
</script>
```

it's not return the routers , but return an obejct like this:
[image]

So what I can do to fix that?

Comment: You're maybe looking for `useRoute` here? Rather than `useRouter`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm usually like this, without using {}

```js
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
const routes = [
 {
   path: "/",
   name: "Home",
   component: Home,
 },
];

const router = new VueRouter({
 mode: "history",
 base: process.env.BASE_URL,
 routes,
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).